# How to check a message if exists before deleting it

Tags: discord.js

So Here is my issue, so the bot has an Auto Moderation system and im trying to make it work while other moderation bots are there too but the issue is that once the message isnot deleted by my bot the bot kept giving me Unknown Message error cuz it has been deleted by another bot so is there a way to check if the message still exists before deleting

Edit: I Fixed the issue by fetching the message and if the message exists the message will get deleted

Comment: `if (message) message.delete()` ?

Comment: nope that didnot work it still gives the error